# Superior and Inferior in <input type = number>

Tags: javascript, html

I got a strange behaviour:

javascript:

```
function Compare(x, y) {
    var min = document.getElementById(x).value
    var max = document.getElementById(y).value
    if (min > max) {
        alert("la prix MINIMAL est SUPÉRIEUR au prix MAXIMAL!")
        document.formacha.min.focus()
    }
```

}

```
<input type="number" id="max" min="0"/>
<input type="number" id="min" min="0" onblur="Compare('min', 'max')">
```

so:

if

```
max = 1000000000000000
min = 10
```

it is ok, but if i change

```
min = 11
```

then

```
alert("la prix MINIMAL est SUPÉRIEUR au prix MAXIMAL!")
```

is fired!

it is like the browser considers that `min > max` !

Comment: looks like a string problem.

Comment: You're comparing strings, not numbers.

Comment: Yep, you should use `parseFloat` or `parseInt`, whichever is more appropriate.

Comment: but why 10 is considered true?

Comment: form values are STRINGS. you need to convert to numbers with parseInt.

Comment: do a parseInt on values

Comment: `parseInt(document.getElementById(x).value, 10)`

Comment: `'11' > '1000000'` is TRUE, because you're comparing strings. `11 > 10000` is FALSE, because those are integers.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1133814/2295964

Comment: ah, because i was comparing two strings! now i get it, thank you all :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Values of inputs are strings. Here's how JavaScript compares `11` and `100` as strings:

- 1 compared to 1: equal, continue to next character
- 1 compared to 0: 1 is higher, therefore `11` is higher then `100`.

Try converting to numbers:

```
var min = parseInt(document.getElementById(x).value,10);
var max = parseInt(document.getElementById(y).value,10);
```

Comment: First, before doing that it checks whether one is a substring of the other, if the right is a substring of the left, then it will return true, if vice versa it will return false, and if neither it will do what you said.

Comment: why in HTNL5 it is not automaticaly converted when the type is `number` ?

Comment: Probably for compatibility with browsers that don't support HTML5.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `parseInt` to compare integer values

```
 var minValue=parseInt(min, 10);
 var maxValue=parseInt(max, 10);
```